# Hide ?ver=1.0 from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching, url-rewriting

So I was having a problem with my site caching and having users not get an update until days later. After trying several solutions using the .htaccess file, the one that worked the best for my situation was by simply adding ?ver=1.0 to the end of all my links to other files. When I make an update to the site I can easily find and replace all instances of that text.

This solution isn't the nicest but its the best thing I can get to work every time. Updates to the site are sporadic so meta tags aren't of much help. The only downside of this method is that now the address bar shows the URL followed by that text. Personally, I find it an eyesore and was wondering how to either get rid of it with a script or by changing the method I control the cache.

I tried using the .htcaccess file again with using `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]` but I seem to have bad luck using that file. I am more of a designer so I usually don't mess around with server code.

I would appreciate any help on this topic. I have been messing around all day on these two things, caching and changing the URL appearance but I just can't do it. Even just providing links to places where I can read more and expand my general knowledge would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Caching is done by the client.  If you remove that from the URL, it won't do anything at all.  You need to learn about HTTP caching headers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Was there one in specific you would recommend I should try? I couldn't really find one that fit my needs since updates to the website are so sporadic. They can range from 5 times a week to once a month.